# Questions tagged with both "linked" and "list"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are [292 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked+list) tagged with both [linked](/questions/tagged/linked) and [list](/questions/tagged/list). Almost all of them are supposed to be tagged with [linked-list](/questions/tagged/linked-list), is there some way to clean this up?

I'm not familiar with questions tagged with [linked](/questions/tagged/linked) but without [list](/questions/tagged/list), but is [linked](/questions/tagged/linked) a good tag? It doesn't have a wiki yet.

Comment: **+1** Burninate [tag:linked] already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[linked](/questions/tagged/linked) has the hallmarks of a bad tag. It doesn't seem to mean anything.

Feel free to go through the tag and retag the questions to better tags. A question tagged [linked](/questions/tagged/linked) [list](/questions/tagged/list) should probably be tagged [linked-list](/questions/tagged/linked-list), just [list](/questions/tagged/list), or both instead, but do read the post to make sure. And please fix other issues with the question while you're at it (spelling, formatting, other tags, title, …).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, [linked](/questions/tagged/linked) is not a good tag.

But you can't directly change all the questions tagged under [list](/questions/tagged/list) to [linked-list](/questions/tagged/linked-list). Because there are a lot of questions related to `C# lists` and `android list view` tagged under the [list](/questions/tagged/list) tag.

So either re-tagging the specific question is better, but it'll take too much time and effort.

Comment: I know "list" is a perfectly good tag. That's one of the problems.