# Remove the "Linked" Tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, ambiguous-tags

The [linked](/questions/tagged/linked) tag on Stack Overflow has no tag wiki, no summary, and is ambiguous as to what it does.

Referring to Jeff's Criteria on [Meta-Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag

By itself [linked](/questions/tagged/linked) doesn't tell me anything useful about the question. A question tagged as Linked would need additional tags to give it any useful context.

> If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag

This is where the biggest issue with this tag is; it is ambiguous as to what "linked" it is referring to. Looking at the tag it is heavily used by questions which refer to [linked-list](/questions/tagged/linked-list) which has its own tag, but has also been used on other questions including linked objects, linking in HTML, LinkedIn, and other uses.

At the moment this tag is ambiguous and subjective in its usage and should either be burninated or synonymized with [linked-list](/questions/tagged/linked-list) and removed from the questions which do not concern linked lists.

[image: Woo]

Comment: I see a few uses that should be changed to [tag:symlink], so an all-out retag is not probably the best option here.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188949/questions-tagged-with-both-linked-and-list